How to show that integral of density(kernal) function $\phi_{\sigma}$ over $\mathbb{R}$is equal to 1.
I am currently studying a paper published in the "Journal of Approximation Theory" on Neural Networks. We have the following definitions:
Definition(Sigmoidal functions):A function $\sigma:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is said to be sigmoidal function if it satisfies $$\lim_{x\rightarrow-\infty} σ(x) = 0 ~\text{and}~
\lim_{x\rightarrow+\infty} σ(x) = 1.$$
Further, we consider a sigmoidal function that is non-decreasing and satisfying three conditions:
$$~(S1)~ σ(x) − 1/2~ \text{is an odd function};\\
(S2)~ σ ∈ C^2(\mathbb{R})~ \text{is concave for}~ x ≥ 0;\\
(S3)~ σ(x) = O(|x|^{−α}) ~\text{as}~ x → −∞,~\text{ for some}~ α > 1,$$
Defintion($\phi_{\sigma}$):Now we define the kernal function $\phi_{\sigma}$ as follows:
$\phi_{\sigma} :=1/2
[σ(x + 1) − σ(x − 1)],~ x ∈ \mathbb{R}$.
Now i have to prove the following lemma:

Lemma 2.2. Let $\sigma$ be as sigmoidal function as in the Definition above, and let $\alpha$ be as in condition (S3). Then

(i) $\phi_{\sigma} (x) ≥ 0$ for every $x ∈ \mathbb{R}$, with $\phi_{\sigma}(1) > 0$, and moreover $\lim_{
x→±∞}
\phi_{\sigma}(x) = 0;$
(ii) The function $\phi_{\sigma}(x)$ is even;
(iii) The function $\phi_{\sigma} (x)$:
is non-decreasing for $x < 0$ and non-increasing for $x ≥ 0$;
(iv) $\phi_{\sigma} (x) = O(|x|^{−α})$, as $x→ ±∞$.

Furthermore, $\phi_{\sigma} ∈ L^1(R)$;

(v) For every $x ∈ \mathbb{R}$,
$\sum_{
k∈\mathbb{Z}}
\phi_\sigma(x − k) = 1,$
and
$∥\phi_{\sigma} ∥_1 =
\int_{\mathbb{R}}
\phi_{\sigma} (x) dx =
1$


I have proved all parts of lemma but is not able the prove that integral of density function is 1 over reals i.e how to prove that $$ ||\phi_{\sigma} ||_1 =
\int_{\mathbb{R}}
\phi_{\sigma} (x) dx =
1$$ i think it follows directly from $\sum_{
k∈\mathbb{Z}}
\phi_\sigma(x − k) = 1,$ but still not able to compplete.Please help me to complete the proof.
Also i do not understand $\phi_{\sigma} ∈ L^1(R)$ knowing $\phi_{\sigma} (x) = O(|x|^{−α})$
Thanks in advance!!

Just integrate $\sum_{
k∈\mathbb{Z}}
\phi_\sigma(x − k) = 1,$ from $0$ to $1$.

@geetha290krm thanks for hint. What about second part of my question, i.e., $\phi_{\sigma} ∈ L^1(R)$ knowing $\phi_{\sigma} (x) = O(|x|^{−α})? $

Integrability of $\phi_\sigma$ follows from assumptions S2 and S3. The former implies that $\phi$ is continuous and thus bounded in any closed subinterval in the real line; the latter implies that there is a constant $a>0$ such that
$$|\phi(x)|\leq \frac{1}{|x|^\alpha}\qquad \text{for}\, |x|>a$$
It is known from Calculus that $f(x)=\frac{1}{x^\alpha}$ is integrable on $[a,\infty)$ whenever $\alpha>1$; hence
$$\|\phi_\alpha\|_1=\int_{[-a,a]}|\phi_\sigma(x)\,dx+\int_{\{|x|>a\}}|\phi_\sigma(x)|\,dx<2a\sup\{|\phi(x)|:|x|\leq a\} +\int_{\{|x|>a\}}x^{-\alpha}dx<\infty$$
